# how to get MAC Address of Wifi connected device in android

Tags: java, android, mac-address

```
WifiManager wifimanager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo winfo = wifimanager.getConnectionInfo();
String MACAddress = winfo.getMACAdress();
```

Hello
This code only give me my MAC Adress.But I want to get MAC Address of connected devices.

for example: A devices connected to B devices so B can see MAC Address of A  devices.

i want the code for android ;
thx

Comment: I doubt this is possible.

Comment: This information would be in the ARP table. I'm not sure if you can get this information from Android APIs though.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Even if you get access to the ARP table somehow, it is another thing to get a list of active connections.

Comment: Correlate the information with that of netstat then. The OP isn't clear on what "connected" means. Is the phone an AP? Is he looking for other devices connected to the same AP? Devices with active TCP connections to the phone?

Answer (score 1):

It is called **Android Network Discovery** and interested developers can get its source code from http://bit.ly/QrIwLB

Sorry for late answer.But Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Please do not use a link shortener. Otherwise you can't see where the link points to. (Is it safe?) https://github.com/rorist/android-network-discovery